# Adding a row with multiple columns using Node.js & sqllite3

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, express

Using Node.JS with the SQLlite3 module I created a table: 'users' in my database with 2 columns: 'name' and 'surname'.

```
// Importing database
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'test.db';
var exists = fs.existsSync(file);
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database(file)

//inserting first user
db.run('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?)', ['"John", "Doe"'])
db.close();
```

Instead of adding the value 'John' to 'name' and 'Doe' to surname, it adds the value ' "John", "Doe" ' to name and null to surname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter of db.run should have been passed as an array when using multiple placeholders instead of a string. Solution:

```
db.run('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?)', ['John', 'Doe'])
db.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for stating the most simple and direct answer which is not answered in proper tutorials also!